# Div not transparent. Text inside transparent. Is this possible? How to do it?

Tags: html, css, text, transparent

This is what i wanna do
[image]

Help me pls, i think this may not be working or its just not enough to do

```css
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [transparent div over an image but opaque text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679093/transparent-div-over-an-image-but-opaque-text)

Comment: @emmanuel that question is completely different

Comment: Just in case - are you using `position`?

Comment: #description {cursor:default;position:fixed;width:100%;height:88%;z-index:1;opacity:0.5;background-color:black;font-size:0.03rem;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

Comment: -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
-ms-text-fill-color: transparent;
-o-text-fill-color: transparent;
text-fill-color: transparent; appears to be red in Notepad++, so i sopose that i m going in totaly wrong direction

Answer (score 3):

The best way I know to do this is to set the same background on the container element and the element with the text in it. In this case, you'll need a middle containing element for the translucent black background. Here's what I came up with:

```css
div,
aside span {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/nature);
}
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
aside {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
aside span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: arial;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <aside>
    <span>HERE IS SOME TEXT</span>
  </aside>
</div>
```

So the magic is the styling on the span. You were on the right track but we needed to have that background in place on the span itself so we could clip it to the text.

This solution only works in webkit!

Answer (score 0):

Ty for the answer, 1+ from me, but since I want the background to be completely independent from the text, I came up with this simple solution and how to "go around the problem".

Instead of making a text within a div, I will greate a GIF image where certain pixels will be transparent (or non existing actualy).